# Meteor + node-amqp: unable to connect via SSL to RabbitMQ server

Tags: node.js, meteor, rabbitmq, node-amqp

I am using node-amqp in a Meteor app to connect to a rabbitMQ server via SSL.  Here is my connection string:

```
var rConn = AMQP.createConnection({ url: amqps://user:pass@host:pppp, vhost: '/virthost' });
```

However, no connection is made.  The following is in the RabbitMQ error log:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 25-Jun-2013::17:41:30 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.20247.0> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp)

=ERROR REPORT==== 25-Jun-2013::17:41:30 ===
error on AMQP connection <0.20231.0>: {ssl_upgrade_error,"record overflow"} (unknown POSIX error)

=INFO REPORT==== 25-Jun-2013::18:11:35 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.22556.0> (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:pppp)

=ERROR REPORT==== 25-Jun-2013::18:11:40 ===
error on AMQP connection <0.22556.0>: {ssl_upgrade_error,timeout} (unknown POSIX error)
```

All I can find on the record overflow error is to check the version of Erlang that is running.  The box with which I'm attempting to make the connection is using the most recent version.  I'm not sure of the box running RabbitMQ, but I'll look into it.  Any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rather late response at this point, I'm afraid, but I just had a similar problem and it turned out I was piping plaintext into the RabbitMQ server socket. The server was expecting an SSL negotiation, but my client-side code hadn't correctly set up an SSL socket and instead used a regular socket, resulting in a "record overflow" just like this one- though mine was over STOMP and looked like this:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Oct-2015::15:03:10 ===
STOMP detected TLS upgrade error on <0.1224.0> (127.0.0.1:52065 -> 127.0.0.1:61614): alert record overflow
```

http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-December/071099.html was the giveaway.

So, I'm providing this answer in the hope that the next person to view this question checks what their client is spewing into the socket.